# ToggleButton change state on orientation changed

Tags: android, orientation, togglebutton

I have a `CustomButton` class (extends `LinearLayout`) where I inflate a layout which contains a `ToggleButton` (in reality this is more complex, but I simplified here the problem).

```
public class CustomButton extends LinearLayout {

    private ToggleButton toggleOnOffButton;

    public CustomButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.custom_button_layout, this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onFinishInflate() {
        toggleOnOffButton = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggle_on_off_button);
        super.onFinishInflate();
    }

    public ToggleButton getToggleOnOffButton() {
        return toggleOnOffButton;
    }
}
```

custom_button_layout.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ToggleButton android:id="@+id/toggle_on_off_button"
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:textOff="Off"
                  android:textOn="On"
                  android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            />
</RelativeLayout>
```

I have an activity where I inflate an layout with 2 `CustomButton`-s. 
The on/off state of the first toggleButton is saved in shared preferences and I load the value from there in `onCreate` method.

```
public class FirstActivity extends Activity
{
    private CustomButton customButton;
    private ToggleButton toggleBut;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        customButton = (CustomButton)findViewById(R.id.toggleButton);
        toggleBut = customButton.getToggleOnOffButton();

        boolean saved = loadPreferences("toggleBut");
        toggleBut.setChecked(saved);
        toggleBut.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                boolean checked = toggleBut.isChecked();
                savePreferences("toggleBut", checked);
            }
        });
    }

    private void savePreferences(String key, boolean value){
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putBoolean(key, value);
        editor.commit();
    }

    private boolean loadPreferences(String key){
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
        return sharedPreferences.getBoolean(key, true);
    }
}
```

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"> 
    <com.example.example.cs.ssd.custom.CustomButton
            android:id="@+id/toggleButton"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />

    <com.example.example.cs.ssd.custom.CustomButton
            android:id="@+id/toggleButton2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />
</LinearLayout>
```

When I start the application the first toggleButton is ON. When I change the orientation of the screen, automatically the first toggleButton become Off, even `saved` has value `true` and is called `toggleBut.setChecked(saved);` and I think this has to do with the `CutomButton` I've created because if the `main.xml` layout contains only 1 `CustomButton` this problem does not reproduce. 
I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong...
Here is the archive with the above code (as a project): [archive](http://minus.com/lbk3q4IKQfJPEB)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want your CustomButton to retain its current state after an orientation change simply override onSaveInstanceState() and onRestoreInstanceState().

**A Solution**

I ran through your code and noticed that `toggleBut`'s state was being changed after onActivityCreated() but before onStart(). To avoid having any of these methods override your toggle settings, I simply moved these lines from onViewCreated():

```
boolean saved = loadPreferences("toggleBut");
toggleBut.setChecked(saved);
```

and put them in onResume(). Hope that helps!

**Better Solution**

Your ToggleButton setting are being overwritten when the system tries to restore the default `saveInstanceState`, probably in Fragment.onActivityCreated().

In CustomButton, override these functions like so:

```
@Override
protected Parcelable onSaveInstanceState() {
    Bundle state = new Bundle();
    state.putParcelable("default", super.onSaveInstanceState());
    state.putParcelable("toggle", toggleOnOffButton.onSaveInstanceState());
    return state;
}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Parcelable state) {
    Bundle bundle = (Bundle) state;
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(bundle.getParcelable("default"));
    toggleOnOffButton.onRestoreInstanceState(bundle.getParcelable("toggle"));
};
```

Understand that the system will still change the ToggleButton states, without the one more thing. But let me try to explain what;s happening:

- `onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState)` passes it's `savedInstanceState` to every layout element by calling 'onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState)`.
- onRestoreInstanceState() begins with the layout's root element first and traverses up the layout's hierarchy (in this case it sets the checked state of each ToggleButton last).
- Since the default methods are clearly not working, we need to define our own save / restore method for the ToggleButtons. Otherwise any changes we make before the system calls onRestoreInstanceState() will be changed again by the system...

So, lastly we will exclude the ToggleButtons from this default behavior by adding the following line to CustomButton.onFinishInflate():

```
toggleOnOffButton.setSaveEnabled(false);
```

Voila, your CustomButtons automatically retain their state.

Comment: the problem is a little more complex; I'm actually using fragments and in the application I cannot change the screen orientation - is forced to be portrait. If I replace the fragment which contains those 2 custom buttons with a new one and I came back, also the state of the first toggleButton is changed and I do not see any logic why this happens...

Comment: To be clear: if CustomButtons `A` & `B` are both true, when you return only CustomButton `A` changes it's state to false?

Comment: No, both. Their default value is true, user goes to another activity/fragment and when return both are false.

Comment: To me it sounds like when the layout is redrawn, onCreate() is not being called, which is how the lifecycle should work for simple tab navigation like this. Overriding the functions above in CustomButton will restore the appropriate state anytime the layout is redrawn (not just orientation changes).

Comment: the `onCreate` method is called when I return to the screen and also when the orientation is changed. this line is executed `toggleBut.setChecked(saved);` where `saved` is `true`, but the toggle button became for don't know what reason off.

Comment: What you describe (`toggleBut.setChecked(true)` becomes false only when you return to the Activity) is mind boggling, have you confirmed that `loadPreferences("toggleBut")` returns true every time with the debugger and or logcat statements?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13079/discussion-between-paul-and-sam)

Comment: Yes, `loadPreferences("toggleBut")` always returns true, testes with debugger.
here is the project [link](http://minus.com/lQPxTsmqe4xuf) - using fragments...I simply do not know what is happening

Comment: can you execute your code in `onResume()` ? Since rotating an Activity forces an `onResume()` this could help...

Comment: @Paul Sorry I missed you in chat. I downloaded your code and updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Sam. So, before the fragment is visible to the user, something caused changing the `toggleButton` state, but what and why? 
Actually, by moving those 2 lines in `onResume()` method, before this `onResume()` method is called, the state is changed, and we change again the state in `onResume` to the actually real state (which is retrieved from shared preferences).
It is working now with this change, but I'm still confusing why the state is changed before the fragment is visible to the user.

Comment: @Athmos: Yes, moving the code in `onResume()` solved this problem, but I'm not sure why. Is not realated to the fact that `onResume()` method is called when rotating the screen, because also the `onCreate()` is called everytime when the orientation changes. Also in the example with fragments, I do not change the orientation, but instead I simply replace one fragment with another and return to first fragment.

Comment: @Paul I updated my answer with a detailed description, I hope it clears some things up.

Comment: @Sam: I was 'off' 3 days, just saw your replies. Thanks a lot for your solution and for the time you spend in answering all my questions. It's more-more clear for me now. I am relatively new to Android and I definitely need to better understand all the lifecycle methods and when they are called...  
So, I believe that all this behaviour with toggleButtons is some kind of a Android OS bug... Thanks again!