# Android toggle button display wrong value after orientation change

Tags: android, orientation, tablelayout, togglebutton

Here is my problem.
I've got a simple activity which set a layout, and add rows in a table-layout(itself in a scroll view).
Those table-rows have a custom layout with a text-field and a toggle button.

Each toggle button has a value taken from a database, and when I first create the activity, the values are OK. But when I turn the device and then change the orientation, all the toggles-button take "false" value. I printed the values that I set in the Logcat, and the values are the good ones (those in the database).

I thought something like the layout I want is hidden behind another layout, but I made some tests and the text-fields change with new values, so I really don't understand why the toggle buttons don't work.

Here is the code :
TableRow layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <TableRow xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         >
         <RelativeLayout 
             android:id="@+id/relativelayout_row_parametres"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="50dp"
             android:layout_weight="1.0">
            <TextView 
                android:id="@+id/textview_row_parametres"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                />
            <ToggleButton
                android:id="@+id/togglebutton_row_parametres"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                android:textOn="@string/togglebutton_on"
                android:textOff="@string/togglebutton_off" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </TableRow>
```

Activity Layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView style="@style/header" />

        <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.8"
            android:background="@drawable/gradient_bg"
            android:padding="10dip"
            android:orientation="vertical">

          <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.85"
            android:fillViewport="true"
            android:padding="10dip"
            android:layout_gravity="center">

              <TableLayout 
                  android:id="@+id/tablelayout_parametres"
                  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:background="@drawable/cornered_bg"
                  android:paddingTop="5dip"
                  android:paddingBottom="5dip">

              </TableLayout>

          </ScrollView>
          <Button 
              android:id="@+id/button_parametres_accept"
              android:gravity="center"
              android:text="@string/accept_changes"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="0dp"
              android:layout_weight="0.15"
              android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
          </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

And the activity code:

```
public class Parameters extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        final Map<String, Boolean> changes = new HashMap<String, Boolean>();
        final Context ctx = getApplicationContext();
        LanguageManager.updateConfig(this);

        setContentView(R.layout.parametres);

        CountryDB[] countries = Database.instance(getApplicationContext()).getCountries();

        TableLayout tabLayout = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tablelayout_parametres);
        for(int i =0; i<countries.length; i++){
            TableRow newRow = (TableRow) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.row_parametres, null);
            TextView textView = (TextView) newRow.findViewById(R.id.textview_row_parametres);

            ToggleButton toggleButton = (ToggleButton) newRow.findViewById(R.id.togglebutton_row_parametres);
            toggleButton.setChecked(countries[i].isToSynchronize());
            toggleButton.setTag(countries[i]);
            Log.e("setChecked",""+toggleButton.getId()+"/"+countries[i].isToSynchronize());

            textView.setText(countries[i].getLabel());

            toggleButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    CountryDB countryTemp = (CountryDB) v.getTag();
                    changes.put(countryTemp.getLabel(), ((ToggleButton)v).isChecked());
                }
            });

            tabLayout.addView(newRow);

            TableRow rowDivider = (TableRow) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.row_divider, null);
            tabLayout.addView(rowDivider);
        }

        Button buttonValidation = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_parameters_accept);
        buttonValidation.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Iterator<String> iterator = changes.keySet().iterator();
                while(iterator.hasNext()){
                    String stringTemp = iterator.next();
                    Database.instance(ctx).updateCountry(stringTemp, changes.get(stringTemp));
                }

                Intent intent = new Intent(ctx, Splash.class);

                String result = "restart";
                String from = "parameters";
                Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
                returnIntent.putExtra("result", result);
                returnIntent.putExtra("from", from);
                setResult(RESULT_OK, returnIntent);

                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

    }

}
```

In the Log.e, I print the values, and they are good, the display on togglebuttons is wrong, they are just all "false".

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Between onCreate() and onResume() , Android tries to restore the old state of the toggle Buttons. Since they don't have unique ID's , Android wont succeed and everything is false again. Try to move your setChecked() calls into onResume() ( maybe onStart() works too).

Here is a pretty good answer to the same Question:

[ToggleButton change state on orientation changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11213864/togglebutton-change-state-on-orientation-changed)

Comment: The thing is, I can't select a toggle button except when I create it (because they are added dynamically and all have the same id...). So I moved all the code from onCreate to onStart. But it's not working better.

Comment: You can use a HashMap to keep a connection between the countries and the corresponding toggleButton. `HashMap <CountryDB, ToggleButton> mHashMap = new HashMap <CountryDB, ToggleButton>;` then when creating all the buttons: `mHashMap.put(countries[i],toggleButton);` later you can just go through the countries array again and enable /disable the toggleButton you get from the HashMap

Comment: My bad, I didn't try with the code in "onResume", and it's working.
Not in "onStart", but working in "onResume".

Answer (score -1):

you have to save data before Orientation.

Android have method `onSaveImstamceState(Bundle outState)` and `onRestoreInstanceState(BundleInstaceState)`

override these method in Activity.

Comment: I don't get why I need to save data, I take them from database, it's not temporary values chosen by the user.

Answer (score -1):

There's a simpler solution: you only need to add configChanges property to your activity declaration, like stated [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html#HandlingTheChange). This way you can prevent Activity restart when orientation changes. So in your manifest you should have something like

```
<activity android:name=".Parameters"
      android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden">
```

or if your buildTarget>=13

```
<activity android:name=".Parameters"
      android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize">
```

**Edit**: Like reported on comments below, this is not an optimal solution. The main drawback is reported in a note of the document linked above:

> Note: Handling the configuration change yourself can make it much more difficult to use alternative resources, because the system does not automatically apply them for you. This technique should be considered a last resort when you must avoid restarts due to a configuration change and **is not recommended for most applications**.

Comment: Nice, this one works. But it doesn't explain why those crazy toggle button don't set the value I gave them :p
I'll take this solution anyway, thanks.

Comment: Yes, and you wont be able to use alternative resources/layout for landscape and portrait. `Note: Handling the configuration change yourself can make it much more difficult to use alternative resources, because the system does not automatically apply them for you. This technique should be considered a last resort when you must avoid restarts due to a configuration change and is not recommended for most applications.`

Comment: @YallaT. I know the drawbacks of this solution, and I linked the official document for reference. It's not intended as a "working everywhere" solution. BTW if you don't use different resources for portrait and landscape, my answer give an _effective_ way to solve the issue. So, why downvote?

Comment: Because i dont think Solutions that have pretty big drawbacks should not be advised so freely - sure it may work in this case, but other people with the same problem who stumble upon this question may suffer from these drawbacks. I think you should have at least noted that this is not optimal - not only by linking the offical document. But you're right, downvoting was a bit harsh, you're still helping this guy out.